# Script not printing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to print a script using jquery but the script code is not printed and the rest is, does anyone know how to solve this? Following code below:

```
codigo = '<div id="teste"><input type="submit" id="botao" value="Send" /><script>$("#botao").click(function() { alert("test"); });</script></div>';
$('#iframe5').parent().after(codigo);
```

Comment: Sorry, the quotes are correct, I was wrong to type here without quotes

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with quotes. Try changing the quotes properly and everything should work just fine.

codigo = '$(\'#botao\').click(function() { alert(\'test\'); });';
$('#iframe5').parent().after(codigo);

I guess this should work.

Try adding \' for escaping quotes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, the quotes are correct, I was wrong to type here without quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
codigo = '<div id="teste"><input type="submit" id="botao" value="Send" /><script>$("#botao").click(function() { alert("test"); });</script></div>';
$('#iframe5').parent().after(codigo);
```

there was a problem with your quotes